# How to connect a thermistor to a micro-controller?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, thermistor

I was following a datasheet of a micro-controller and I got confused. I have two thermistors (LM 35DZ & TMP36GT9Z.) I would like to connect them to an evaluation board. The picture shows how:

[image]

How can I connect my 3 pin thermistor? (GND, POWER, ANALOG V) It looks like they are using a 2 pin thermistor.

Comment: As pointed out, those part numbers are for 3-terminal thermometer ICs.  A thermistor ("thermal resistor") is a two-terminal part, because it's just a resistor that responds to temperature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [part](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/609/TMP35_36_37-1504323.pdf) [numbers](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf?HQS=dis-mous-null-mousermode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1626098567217&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fbr.mouser.com%252F) you mention are not thermistors at all, but ICs which have an analog output which changes proportionally with temperature changes.

Generally speaking you would supply them with power and connect the output to an ADC input (perhaps with signal conditioning of some kind), but refer to the datasheets for the sensors (which I have linked above) and whatever is connected to your board's analog input in the schematic.